# Different sleep binaries on Mac (Darwin) and in Linux. How to properly handle the differences?

Tags: linux, shell, osx, sleep

In my Linux box, `sleep` accepts seconds, minutes and hours. So:

```
sleep 10m
```

Sleeps for 10 minutes (or 600s).

`sleep` on Mac only accepts seconds as argument. `sleep 10m` doesn't work, only `sleep 600s`.

What can I do? Create a function named `sleep` that converts when 10m or 10h is passed as a parameter to seconds, and calls the builtin sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use homebrew for Mac OS X: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew and install the coreutils package from there. That will allow you to install the GNU version of sleep that handles the same parameters as the linux version.

Note that by default it installs the binaries with a 'g' prefix, so the command will actually be named gsleep, but the package provides a script file to alias all commands.

Comment: This solves my problem, I'm already using homebrew. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`sleep` on Linux accepts seconds too (at least all the versions I've ever seen); can't you just use `sleep 600` on both?

Comment: What if I want to do sleep 16m? Will I have to calculate 16*60 or X*60 everytime I have a different sleep time? This doesn't seems practical to me.

Comment: This has the advantage that it should work on all POSIX-compliant systems.

Comment: @Somebody: You could write a function `sleepmin() { sleep $(($1 * 60)); }`, at least under `bash`.